# windows 7 not installed while instaling windows 7 after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, windows-7

I have installed ubuntu as a fresh os on my dell xps laptop L1410
when i am trying to intall windows 7 for dual boot an error is coming no drivers found also it needs to NTFS formating of hard drive .I am new to linux environment please help me 
*I want to dual boot windows with ubuntu
*do i need to install saperate partition for windows
*no drivers found and even after inserting drivers CD its not recognizing for windows
* need to buy a new laptop which is completely comaptible to Ubuntu 
*i have GTforce NVIDIA graphic card in laptop and also intel rapid storage technoly do ubuntu support it ,and graphic card details not shouwing some other graphic card is appearong NVC Gallium sort of.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI/gpt or BIOS/MBR boot mode? Windows has to be installed in the same boot mode. With BIOS Windows requires a primary partition formatted NTFS with the boot flag on a MBR partitioned drive. Its default install uses two partitions but will install to one. If UEFI it requires multiple partitions and gpt partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the exciting world of Linux systems and free software!

There is a large number of excellent guides and instructions out there, so googling any problem and combining your search term with "Ubuntu" gives excellent results!

No, almost any modern Computer is able to run linux. The key to dualbooting Ubuntu is installing Windows first. After that, the Ubuntu setup is able to install itself alongside Windows. Refer to this guide during the whole process:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot